# Tomcat 7 Jersey Jackson 200 OK but payload gets stripped

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jackson

I made a rest service using Jersey/Jackson and I'm deploying to Tomcat 7 in dev. Locally, using Jetty, when I make the call

https://localhost/usorgws-web/v1/usorg/search/dep?page=2&limit=10

everything works fine and I get a 200 response with the return payload being a list of objects. But when I deploy to our dev environment and make the same call replacing localhost with the server's hostname, I get a 200 Okay, but no payload is returned. I'm sure that it's working because I'm putting print lines in the code and I'm watching the logs. I can see the payload as a populated list propagate from my dao all the way up to my resource. But it looks like as soon as the tomcat container gets a hold of the Response, it strips the payload for some reason. I don't see any errors in the logs

Here is some code:

Resource

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by barryj on 9/14/16.
 */
@Path("/usorg")
@Component
public class USOrgResource {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(USOrgResource.class);

    @Autowired
    private USOrgDao usOrgDao;

    @Autowired
    private USOrgService usOrgService;

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Value("${pagination.limit.default.min}")
    private int minLimit;

    @Value("${pagination.limit.default.max}")
    private int maxLimit;

    @GET
    @Path("orgCode/{orgCode}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUSOrgByOrgCode(@PathParam("orgCode") String orgCode) throws
            SystemException {
        USOrg usOrg = null;
        try {
            usOrg = usOrgDao.getUsOrgByOrgCode(orgCode);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new SystemException();
        }
        ResponseWrapper<USOrg> responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper<>();
        responseWrapper.setData(usOrg);
        responseWrapper.setDescription("USOrg retrieval by org_code");
        responseWrapper.setSuccess(true);
        return Response.status(200).entity(responseWrapper).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("search/{term}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response searchUsOrgWithPagination(@PathParam("term") String term, @QueryParam
            ("page") int page, @QueryParam("limit") int limit) throws SystemException {
        logger.info("hit");
        checkPageBounds(limit);
        USOrgPageResults usOrgPageResults = null;
        try {
            usOrgPageResults = usOrgService.searchUsOrg(term, page, limit);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new SystemException();
        }
        ResponseWrapper<List<USOrg>> responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper<>();
        responseWrapper.setData(usOrgPageResults.getUsOrgList());
        responseWrapper.setDescription("USOrg search");
        responseWrapper.setSuccess(true);

        return buildPaginationResponse(200, responseWrapper, usOrgPageResults);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUSOrg(@QueryParam("page") int page, @QueryParam("limit") int limit) throws
            SystemException {
        logger.info("hit");
        checkPageBounds(limit);
        USOrgPageResults usOrgPageResults = null;
        try {
            usOrgPageResults = usOrgService.getUsOrg(page, limit);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new SystemException();
        }
        ResponseWrapper<List<USOrg>> responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper<>();
        responseWrapper.setData(usOrgPageResults.getUsOrgList());
        responseWrapper.setDescription("USOrg search");
        responseWrapper.setSuccess(true);

        if (responseWrapper.getData() != null)
            logger.info("list size: " + responseWrapper.getData().size());
        else
            logger.info("list is null");
        return buildPaginationResponse(200, responseWrapper, usOrgPageResults);
    }

    private Response buildPaginationResponse(int status, Object entity, USOrgPageResults
            usOrgPageResults) {

        final String PAGE = "?page=";
        final String LIMIT = "&limit=";

        String first = "";
        if (usOrgPageResults.getFirst() != null)
            first = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + PAGE + usOrgPageResults.getFirst().getPage() +
                    LIMIT + usOrgPageResults.getFirst().getLimit();

        String prev = "";
        if (usOrgPageResults.getSelf().getPage() > 0)
            prev = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + PAGE + usOrgPageResults.getPrev()
                    .getPage() + LIMIT + usOrgPageResults.getPrev().getLimit();

        String self = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + PAGE + usOrgPageResults.getSelf().getPage() +
                LIMIT + usOrgPageResults.getSelf().getLimit();

        String next = "";
        if (usOrgPageResults.getNext() != null)
            next = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + PAGE + usOrgPageResults.getNext().getPage() +
                    LIMIT + usOrgPageResults.getNext().getLimit();

        String last = "";
        if (usOrgPageResults.getLast() != null)
            last = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + PAGE + usOrgPageResults.getLast().getPage() +
                    LIMIT + usOrgPageResults.getLast().getLimit();

        return Response.status(status).entity(entity).header("first", first).header
                ("prev", prev).header("self", self).header("next", next).header
                ("last", last).build();
    }

    private void checkPageBounds(int limit) {
        if (limit < minLimit)
            throw new NotAllowedException("The limit requested is below the default limit minimum");
        if (limit > maxLimit)
            throw new NotAllowedException("The limit requested is above the default limit maximum");
    }

    public void setMinLimit(int minLimit) {
        this.minLimit = minLimit;
    }

    public void setMaxLimit(int maxLimit) {
        this.maxLimit = maxLimit;
    }
}
```

Here is the WebApplication class where I register my JacksonJaxbJsonProvider

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class WebApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(USOrgResource.class);
        s.add(JacksonFeature.class);
        s.add(SystemExceptionMapper.class);
        s.add(NotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
        s.add(NotAllowedExceptionMapper.class);
        s.add(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
        s.add(CommonResponseHeaderFilter.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten to the bottom of it yet, but when I comment out the line s.add(CommonResponseHeaderFilter.class) in WebApplication, everything works fine when I deploy to tomcat

```
public class CommonResponseHeaderFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    public CommonResponseHeaderFilter() {
    }

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("x-content-type-options", "nosniff");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Keep-Alive", "timeout=5, max=100");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
    }
}
```